# How to export spreadsheet to CSV without evaluating formulas

Tags: excel-formula, export-to-csv, libreoffice-calc

I'm looking for a way to export a spreadsheet (from MS Excel or LibreOffice Calc) without evaluating formulas so the formulas are stored in the CSV. I know, for example, I could [convert formulas to text in MS Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/822-excel-convert-formula-to-text-string.html#excel) prior to export, but don't want to modify the formulas. It appears the [default behavior for CSV export in MS Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-formatting-and-features-that-are-not-transferred-to-other-file-formats-8fdd91a3-792e-4aef-a5bb-46f603d0e585#bm4) loses the formulas if they're not displayed as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, select the tab with the formulas, then hold "Ctrl" + "~" (the tilde character), then do a File, Save As, and choose .csv.

I tried this and opened the file up in notepad, and the formulas were intact.

Comment: is there a way to do this in Google Sheets?