# Convert spreadsheet to .csv on command line without evaluating formulas

Tags: command-line, formula, export-to-csv, gnumeric, ssconvert

I want to convert a spreadsheet (e.g. .xls or from LibreOffice Calc) to some text format, e.g. .csv, without evaluating formulas so the formulas are stored in the text file. I know that LibreOffice has an option "Save cell formula instead of calculated values" when saving as .csv and according to [How to export spreadsheet to CSV without evaluating formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944201/how-to-export-spreadsheet-to-csv-without-evaluating-formulas/36944458#36944458) Excel can do this too, but I'd like to do it on command line. I know that `ssconvert` from the Gnumeric package can convert on command line but as fa as I ca see there's no option to keep the formulas.

The bigger picture is that I want to write a script that takes two versions of an .ods file, converts them and shows the differences. When only one cell has really changed but many other cells depend on it, then I want to see only the real change.

Answer (score 0):

I have used xls2csv under Cygwin.  Just a Google search shows many implementations.  I would start there.

http://search.cpan.org/~ken/xls2csv-1.07/script/xls2csv

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tested it but it doesn't have any "do not evaluate formulas" option.